# How can I know within a class that a method or constructor is called by Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I have a code with no constructor without parameters. The thing is, if I want to use the model in Entity Framework, I have to add a parameterless constructor, which if used within my code would cause inconsistencies. Also, I keep properties public (that I really want to keep private) so entity framework can fill them.

What I want is to be able to throw an exception if the parameterless constructor or the public property is called within the code, but that it works fine for entity framework obviously.

Comment: Are there any rules in the Entity Framework about the parameterless constructor being public?  Most serialization libraries have similar requirements but the constructor does not have to be public.

Comment: Consider using nHibernate instead of EF

Answer (score 2):

It isn't usually recommended to use classes with parameterized constructors as data models. If you're specifying some input to the construction of an object then it suggests that the class is used more as a service than a representation of an object persisted in your database. This is especially true when using an ORM since you're essentially trying to force a generic mapping technology (EF) to have some knowledge of the use of your models, rather than just their data properties.

One common technique to solving this type of problem is to use Data Transfer Objects (DTOs). Once you've retrieved a more basic object from the database, you can use it to hydrate a more complex one (parameterized constructors and all), which is used by the rest of your application. This separation of concerns also aids testing and persistence ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem with parameterless constructors for WCF and other serialization frameworks.

The way that we resolved it was to add the Obsolete attribute to the parameterless constructor with an explanation about why it wasn't to be used. Then, if it is used in code, it will show up as a warning, which you may be able to fail the build on (we don't bother with this step; the warning is enough).